# Dealing with dates when using Specflow

Tags: c#, .net, regex, bdd, specflow

**1**

I have a Specflow feature like this:

```
Given A date of 1,1,2018
```

When I use "Generate step definitions" a method is produced like this:

```
[Given(@"A date of (.*),(.*)")]
public void GivenADateOf(Decimal p0, int p1)
{
    ScenarioContext.Current.Pending();
}
```

How do I change the method to accept three parameters? i.e.

```
public void GivenADateOf(int p0, int p1, int p2)
{
    ScenarioContext.Current.Pending();
}
```

**2**

Also say I wanted to change the feature to this:

```
Given A date of 1/1/2018
```

How do I change the method to accept one parameter? i.e.

```
public void GivenADateOf(datetime p0)
{
    ScenarioContext.Current.Pending();
}
```

I am new to Specflow.  I have looked here: [How does specflow handle multiple parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31789172/how-does-specflow-handle-multiple-parameters) among other places.

Comment: change the regex, change the feature file step call, ???, profit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SpecFlow allows to specify different regular expressions for catching arguments.

For the first option I would use:

```
[Given(@"A date of ([0-9]*),([0-9]*),([0-9]*)")]
public void GivenADateOf(int day, int month, int year)
{
   ScenarioContext.Current.Pending();
}
```

For the second option I would use regular expression that corresponds to your date format. For example:

```
[Given(@"A date of (.*)")]
public void GivenADateOf(DataTime dataTime)
{
     ScenarioContext.Current.Pending();
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  That is it.  I will accept when it lets me.